# Query on MySQL with multiple joins

Tags: mysql

I use MySQL 5.7 and have the following tables:

```
documents:
---------------------------------------------------------------
id    collection_id  numeric_shelfmark    shelfmark
---------------------------------------------------------------
1         kbt           y024            Y 24 
---------------------------------------------------------------

collections:
---------------------------------------------------------------
id      name                location
---------------------------------------------------------------
kbt     kantonb thur        Thurgau
gbt     lorem               ipsum
----------------------------------------------------------------

subprojects_x_documents
-----------------------------------------------------------------
subproject_id        document_id              
-----------------------------------------------------------------
foo                     1                   
-----------------------------------------------------------------

documents_revisions
-----------------------------------------------------------------
document_id  updated_at   numeric_shelfmark  shelfmark  latest
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1       2016-06-22 10:32:01     y024            Y 24        0
1       2017-09-19 09:19:17     z024            Z 24        1
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

With the following `SELECT` query I could manage to get a list of the documents associated with the subproject and collections:

```
     SELECT `documents`.`id`, `documents`.`collection_id`, 
     `documents`.`numeric_shelfmark`, `shelfmark`, `location`, `name`
     FROM (`documents`)
     JOIN `collections` ON `documents`.`collection_id` = `collections`.`id`
     JOIN `subprojects_x_documents` ON `documents`.`id` = 
     `subprojects_x_documents`.`document_id`WHERE 
     `subprojects_x_documents`.`subproject_id` = 'stgall_lotterie'
     ORDER BY `location`, `name`, `documents`.`sort_order`, `numeric_shelfmark`
```

Now, I'm trying to get the latest ("documents_revisions.latest" = 1) revision of document with:

```
SELECT `documents`.`id`, `documents`.`collection_id`, 

`documents`.`numeric_shelfmark`, `documents`.`shelfmark`, `location`,
 name`FROM (`documents`)JOIN `collections` ON
 `documents`.`collection_id` = `collections`.`id`JOIN 
`documents_revisions` ON `documents_revisions`.`document_id` = 
`documents`.`id`JOIN `subprojects_x_documents` ON `documents`.`id` = 
`subprojects_x_documents`.`document_id` WHERE 
`subprojects_x_documents`.`subproject_id` = 'stgall_lotterie' AND 
`documents_revisions`.`latest` = 1 ORDER BY `location`, `name`, 
`documents`.`sort_order`, `numeric_shelfmark`
```

But this query returns the same list of documents as before and ignores the documents_revisions.latest" = 1 part.

When I update the query to perform the operation on documents_revisons table instead of documents table:

```
SELECT `documents`.`id`, `documents`.`collection_id`,
```

`documents`.`numeric_shelfmark`, `documents`.`shelfmark`, `location`, 
`name`FROM (`documents_revisions`)JOIN `collections` ON 
`documents`.`collection_id` = `collections`.`id`JOIN 
`documents_revisions` ON `documents_revisions`.`document_id` = 
`documents`.`id`JOIN `subprojects_x_documents` ON `documents`.`id` = 
`subprojects_x_documents`.`document_id` WHERE 
`subprojects_x_documents`.`subproject_id` = 'stgall_lotterie' AND 
`documents_revisions`.`latest` = 1 ORDER BY `location`, `name`, 
`documents`.`sort_order`, `numeric_shelfmark`

I get the error message: "Not unique table/alias: 'documents_revisions'"

Comment: Your table name is "documents" - plural - but the column name is "document.id" - singular.  Make them consistent.  I'd recommend renaming the table to "document".  Table names should be singular.

Comment: share your data and structure with https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: Post that specific query which shows this error *Unknown column 'document.id' in 'on clause*, as i can see both queries are identical

Comment: I updated my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Your table is called documents, not document

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some tweaking I got my result with:

SELECT `documents_revisions`.`document_id`, 
`documents_revisions`.`collection_id`, 
`documents_revisions`.`numeric_shelfmark`, 
`documents_revisions`.`shelfmark`, `location`, `name`FROM 
(`documents_revisions`)JOIN `collections` ON 
`documents_revisions`.`collection_id` = `collections`.`id` JOIN 
`subprojects_x_documents` ON `documents_revisions`.`document_id` = 
`subprojects_x_documents`.`document_id` WHERE 
`subprojects_x_documents`.`subproject_id` = 'stgall_lotterie' AND 
`documents_revisions`.`latest` = 1 ORDER BY `location`, `name`, 
`numeric_shelfmark`